# Chef recipe using different usernames and passwords

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

If I have two identical servers, Server A and Server B, both are test environments.  How can I use the same Chef recipe, but use different user details on each server?

For example:

```
Server A
Recipe WebSite to setup IIS, but uses:
UsernameA
PasswordA  ... for the application pool
```

and

```
Server B
Recipe WebSite to setup IIS, but uses:
UsernameA
PasswordB  ... for the application pool
```

In my environment I actually have 10 test environments I need to configure all using the same recipe all with unique usernames and passwords.

Comment: Please don't cross post on multiples sites, the mailing list is a better place for this question. This resume to using attributes or databags and hence is off topic for StackOverflow as seeking for a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The two main ways to get data in to a Chef run are node attributes and data bag items. In this case you would probably want the latter since you're going for a full snowflake setup (i.e. every server is unique). I would probably make one data bag item per server using the node's FQDN or possibly node name. You could then access this from your recipe code like this:

```
item = data_bag_item('passwords', node['fqdn'])
template '/my/iis.config' do
  # Other stuff here ...
  variables username: item['username'], password: item['password']
end
```

You can find more information on data bags and the `template` resource in any Chef tutorial.